# how to setup proxy server to redirect requests based on domain requested

Tags: redirect, proxy, squid

I need to setup a proxy server, so that the "real" servers only receive requests from the proxy and no one else.

Basically, somthing like this:

1. client1 requests someServer1.myproxy.tld
2. myproxy.tld forwards and maintains comunication back and forward to someServer1.tld

   ```
   Client1    Client2    Client3

      \          |          /
       \         |         /
        \        |        /

           ---------------
           | myproxy.tld |
           ---------------

        /        |        \
       /         |         \
      /          |          \
   Server1    Server2     Server3
   ```

Is this possible with squid? If yes, can someone point me in the right direction? If not, which tool is best suited?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need cache_peer and cache_peer_access directives.

Have a look at [this link](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers)