# Route53 Subdomain Creation with IP address and Port Number

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, terraform, amazon-route53

We are using route53 AWS service to create a sub domain from our hosted zone. We have an instance currently running on amazon server with Elastic IP. Once we create route53 record of type A we can only assign the Elastic IP of our instance. This will map to apache default page as port 80 is used as default port with given IP address.

In our scenario we have multiple services running on same instance and we want to use a service runing on port 8153. Our requirments is to map this port automatically with our subdomain. So when we type say "ci.yyyyy.com" it will automatically map to that service running on 8153 port. All these steps should be done by using terraform scripts.

Is there any way to map IP address and port number with sub domain? Any suggestion and comments will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not belong to route53 but you can achieve this using a reverse proxy in front of your servers. e.g use Squid in front of your webserver and redirect based on the domain name from the url. In Squid you can achieve this using [cache_peer_access](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers)

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230177/how-to-setup-proxy-server-to-redirect-requests-based-on-domain-requested) where you see a pretty nice diagram

EDIT: I propose Squid here, but you can find any other reverse proxy tool, like Nginx for example if you prefer

Comment: edit: you may want to have a look at the Application Load Balancer (didn't exist by the time I posted the answer). You can route based at http level with those ones